# What is wrong with my orafetch statement?

Tags: oracle, tcl

For some reason my orafetch statement is returning the error:

```
orafetch: handle 0 not open while executing
```

Can someone please point out where I am going wrong in my statement?

```
if {[catch {
    set crsr [oraopen $DB_LOGON_HANDLE]
} result] } {
    puts "Error $result while creating db handles"
    exit 1
}
set name "select names from customers where name = 'Tim Kyle'"
 
set name_query [orasql $crsr $name ]
set get_name [orafetch $name_query -dataarray -indexbyname]
puts $get_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is sample code [on the Tcler's Wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Oratcl#ce2c4fe4ca13d9b30e2efa7d8dee8543400a8d4065bbc47bb23f7c844575c18a) which I reproduce here:

```sh
# For error reporting:
set program [file tail $argv0]

# Package interface:
package require Oratcl

# Connect to the $env(TWO_TASK) database as USER with PASSWORD:
if [catch {oralogon "USER/PASSWORD"} ora_logon] {
   puts stderr "$program: $ora_logon"
   exit 1
}
if [catch {oraopen $ora_logon} ora_statement] {
   oralogoff $ora_logon
   puts stderr "$program: $ora_statement"
   exit 1
}
#if [catch {oraconfig $ora_statement fetchrows 1024} ora_error] {
#    puts stderr "$program: $ora_error"
#}

# Execute SQL statement:
set sql "SELECT column_1, ... column_N FROM ... WHERE ..."
# Note that for Oratcl 4.x, the $oramsg references have to change to
# [oramsg $ora_statement rc]
if [catch {orasql $ora_statement $sql} ora_error] {
   puts stderr "$program: $ora_error"
} elseif {$oramsg(rc) != 0} {
   puts stderr "$program: $oramsg(errortxt)"
} else {
   # Process each row with column_I bound to var_I:
   while {$oramsg(rc) == 0} {
       if [catch {orafetch $ora_statement \
                           {... $var_1 ... $var_N ...} \
                           '@' var_1 1 ... var_N N} \
                 ora_error] {
           puts stderr "$program: $ora_error"
           break
       } elseif {$oramsg(rc) == 1403} {
           break
       } elseif {$oramsg(rc) != 0} {
           puts stderr "$program: $oramsg(errortxt)"
           break
       }
   }
}

# Disconnect from the $env(TWO_TASK) database:
if [catch {oraclose $ora_statement ora_error] {
   puts stderr "$program: $ora_error"
}
if [catch {oralogoff $ora_logon ora_error] {
   puts stderr "$program: $ora_error"
}
```

Which all seems *very* complicated to me! Especially everything to do with `oramsg` (which is what seems to be missing from your code) and `orafetch` binding.

---

You might consider using [`tdbc::oracle`](https://tcl.sowaswie.de/repos/fossil/tdbc_oratcl/index) as a wrapper, which follows the standard [TDBC](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/TDBC) model (which in turn was developed based on experience with best practices in *many* database interfaces).

```sh
package require tdbc::oracle

tdbc::oratcl connection create db USER/PASSWORD@SID
db foreach rec { select names from customers where name = 'Tim Kyle' } {
    puts $rec
}
# Optionally shut everything down at the end with:
#   db destroy
```